# Can I build an azure service bus client and server app using .NET 3.5?

Tags: azure

My application must be .net 3.5.    I would like to use the azure service bus relay to facilitate machine to machine communication.   All examples that i find require .NET 4.0 (NuGet Package).   Does anyone know for sure if i can use .net 3.5 or am i wasting my time evaluating azure?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the REST API and simply use the [WebClient](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/19/common-service-bus-queue-operations-with-the-rest-api.aspx) class to interact with the service bus. Note that [not all features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh780771) are supported by the REST API.

Answer (score 0):

We do have a Service Bus client SDK targeting .NET 35: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19925

You can install the SDK MSI and then use the Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll included there. Do note that this msi will modify some settings in your machine.config etc.